# R running out memory for large data set

Tags: r

I am running my code in a PC and I don't think I have problem with the RAM.
When I run this step:

```
dataset <- rbind(dataset_1, dataset_2,dataset_3,dataset_4,dataset_5)
```

I got the

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 261.0 Mb

The dataset_1 until dataset_5 have around 5 million observation each.

Could anyone please advise how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a "problem with RAM" (since you give no details of the amount of RAM or the structure of the datasets) or a "problem with insufficient searching". R needs sufficient _contiguous_ memory at the time of the call to construct a temporary object and also a final named object. Please  search SO for: `[r] cannot allocate vector ` for many, many similar questions in the past.

Comment: What does `memory.size()` and `memory.limit()` say?

Comment: memory.size() and memory.limit() say `Inf` Warning message:`memory.size()` is Windows-specific .Warning message:``memory.limit()` is Windows-specific.

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages available that may solve your problem under the [High Performance Computing CRAN taskview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html). See "Large memory and out-of-memory data", the ff package, for example.

Answer (score 1):

R, as matlab, load all the data into the memory which means you can quickly run out of RAM (especially for big datasets). The only alternative I can see is to partition your data (i.e. load only part of the data), do the analysis on that part and write the results to files before loading the next chunk.

In your case you might want to use Linux tools to merge the datasets.
Say you have two files `dataset1.txt` and `dataset2.txt`, you can merge them using the shell command `join`, `cat` or `awk`.

More generally, using Linux shell tools for parsing big datasets is usually much faster and requires much less memory.